# Core Data: Get all rows not already fetched

Tags: objective-c, arrays, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a table with two columns, `a` and `b`. The entries in the table have corresponding values `{a: a_i, b: b_i}`.

I get an `NSArray` containing multiple `{a: a_i, b: b_i}` entries, and would like to fetch all entries that are not yet in the array.

One method that could work is to split the array into two arrays, one holding the A values and one holding the B values.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (a IN %@) AND NOT (b in %@)", 
    [input valueForKey:@"a"], [input valueForKey:@"b"]];
```

NSArray valueForKey documentation:

> Returns an array containing the results of invoking `valueForKey:` using *key* on each of the array's objects.

However, I think that there must be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"!((a IN %@.a) && (b IN %@.b))", input, input];
```